# Как можно менять прозрачность материала через код?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Привет! Кто знает, расскажите пожалуйста! Как можно менять прозрачность материала через код?Т.е. у меня есть объект, и нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку он становился на половину прозрачным, и что бы было видно, что находится внутри этого объекта. В интернете рылся, но ничего толком не нашел! :(

Answer (score 0):

Через материал.

Вот я нашел у себя такой пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А затем в скрипте меняешь альфа канал:

```
 gameObject.GetComponent<Material>().color = new Color(r,g,b,a);
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, задал отдельный вопрос. Через startSpeed тоже пробовал, не работает. Через startLifeTime изменяются значения в самом партикле, но длинна его не изменяется